# Query on page executed through php exec() function

Tags: php, mysql, exec

I'm having trouble with an insert query on a page which is executed by another php file using exec() function. So I've got a cron.php that looks like this:

```
while($something = mysql_fetch_assoc($t_result)){

                    exec("C:/xampp/php/php.exe -f C:/xampp/htdocs/xpresslane/scripts/sample.php ".$something['accountID']." '".$something['equipmentID']."' ".$something['another_thing']);                     


            }
```

and then I got sample.php like this:

```
$qry = "insert into a_table (accountID,equipmentID,startDate,endDate,distance) values (".$argv[1].",".$argv[2].",'".$startdate."','".$enddate."','".$distance."');";
```

The funny thing is the $argv variables are inserted correctly. The other 3 however is not. It's inserted as if they don't have value. When I don't go through the exec() and just execute the sample.php file, it's inserted correctly.

I have no idea what's causing it to fail like this. Recreating the date as a date object, but to no avail. I was hoping you guys have an idea how to fix this.

Comment: How are variables $startdate and $enddate being generated?

Comment: They're from the database, via query.